# Embedded widths for the font 'EYRMSN+CMMI12' inconsistent with font dictionary

Tags: pdf-a

I want to make my document compatible with the standard PDF/A 1b. Using an online validator for PDF/A 1b, I got just one warning and two errors.

```
<problem severity="warning" objectID="935" clause="p32" standard="xmp">Recommended padding is not found in the XMP packet trailer</problem>
<problem severity="error" objectID="682" clause="6.3.6" standard="pdfa">Embedded widths for the font 'EYRMSN+CMMI12' inconsistent with font dictionary</problem>
<problem severity="error" objectID="683" clause="6.3.6" standard="pdfa">Embedded widths for the font 'JRLRFJ+CMR12' inconsistent with font dictionary</problem>
```

I am using the newest TexLive.

Comment: I am unsure, whether this question is connected to TeX at all, but please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This is an error with PDF/A 1b standard validation. Anybody who knows what font dictionary is, should give some insight.

Comment: @RokKralj you could help people to help by giving more information, how are you making the pdf, pdflatex? xelatex? ps2pdf? which version of cmr12 did you start with (type 1?)

Comment: google suggests this page which basically says not to worry about it (no idea if that is a good answer:-) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdfnet-sdk/L2osfwaap98

Comment: Yes, pdflatex. I have used T1 as fontenc. I am worrying because a document is either compatible or it is not. And because I have already spent 5 hours making it compatible.

Comment: Please provide an MWE. Otherwise, we are just whistling in the dark and, tuneful though we may be, it won't be much help to you. In any case, probably more like a cacophony. If you are using `microtype`, drop it. No idea if that will help but without a score, it is about the only thing I can think to whistle.